# Run authlib example server from pycharm?

Tags: windows, pycharm, authlib

I just downloaded [this](https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server) project. Try to run it from command line, everything works. Try to run it from pycharm - I get this error:

> c:\Users\Ignas\Anaconda3\envs\ugpsts\python.exe -m flask run
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Ignas\Anaconda3\envs\ugpsts\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
>       mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
>     File "C:\Users\Ignas\Anaconda3\envs\ugpsts\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
>       return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
>     File "C:\Users\Ignas\Anaconda3\envs\ugpsts\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
>       **import**(pkg_name)
>     File "C:\Users\Ignas\Anaconda3\envs\ugpsts\lib\site-packages\flask__init__.py", line 21, in 
>       from .app import Flask, Request, Response
>     File "C:\Users\Ignas\Anaconda3\envs\ugpsts\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 25, in 
>       from . import cli, json
>     File "C:\Users\Ignas\Anaconda3\envs\ugpsts\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 18, in 
>       import ssl
>     File "C:\Users\Ignas\Anaconda3\envs\ugpsts\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in 
>       import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>   `

This error doesn't really tell much to me, what could be wrong? When I runt it from cmd, I use `flask run` command. So nothing really different.

Comment: If you have solved this problem, you can answer your own question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue in PyCharm with conda environments: [PY-27234](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27234). For the workaround you can set the correct `PATH` in the Run Configuration environment variables. It can be obtained from the terminal outside of PyCharm with `echo %PATH%` after env activation.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. But this solution also not working.